# How to get image url of img tag in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, image

I'm creating a wordpress theme. and i want some of the images to remain static. how can i get the url behind my image source.

My Default Image URL
 `<img src="assets/logo/logo.jpg">`

I was trying `<img src="../assets/logo/logo.jpg">`

Is there any function of wordpress that we can use to get the url of an image?

Comment: Your image is in your theme folder?

Comment: yes its in my theme folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the full path of the theme folder too you can do it like this

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/logo/logo.jpg">
```