# How to get a url of an image tag with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating wordpress theme. and want to keep images static. i'm using img tags in my HTML `<img src="assets/logo/logo.jpg">`. I just want to get the url of my image. i was trying `<img src="../assets/logo/logo.jpg`">`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get image url of img tag in wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916762/how-to-get-image-url-of-img-tag-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your assets folder is in the template directory you could use `bloginfo('template_directory');` like this `<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/logo/logo.jpg" alt="logo">`

Answer (score 1):

If you are outputting the template directory in a string e.g.

```
$output .= '<div class="listitem">';
    $output .= '<img src="' . get_bloginfo("template_directory") . '/assets/images/property-not-found.png" />';
$output .= '</div>';
```

You need to use the `get_bloginfo("template_directory")`

Hope this answer will help anyone else who got stuck on this in the future.